# Delete all Objects with a specific name

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice-calc

I'm searching for a better solution to a problem that occures when converting files between MS Excel and Libre Office Calc.

For the error description you can see https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/19176/infinite-white-boxes/ which has a solution which doesn't work for me because it hides too much.

I have written a butt-ugly function, which works, but on rare occasions crashes excel:

```
Private Sub DelCustomShapes_Click()
Dim objDrawingObject As Object
1:
For Each objDrawingObject In Tabelle1.DrawingObjects
    If objDrawingObject.Name = "CustomShape 1" Then
        objDrawingObject.Delete
        GoTo 1
    End If
Next objDrawingObject
End Sub
```

If I omit the problematic Goto, then Next won't work as soon as the first object got deleted and I get an error message + I would need to call the function more than 100 times to get rid of alle white boxes.
How do I delete all objects with one specific name in less ugly?

Comment: If you remove the `GoTo`, what error gets thrown, and at what line?  Could it *perhaps* be, that when you delete `CustomShape 1`, do you expect `CustomShape 2` to get renamed automatically to `1`? I assume you only have one `CustomShape 1` in the worksheet.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but what do you need the `GoTo` statement for... I would think that the code goes through all objects on the sheet and deletes it if it is named "CustomShape 1".

Comment: I have more than 100 objects called "CustomShape 1" which get created by a Conversion-Bug that hasn't been fixed yet. Those are big white boxes and thus need to be dealt with. If I omit GoTo, then in the Line with "Next objDrawingObject" I get different errors from which the last I could reproduce is "Laufzeitfehler '-2147417848 (80010108)': Automatisierungsfehler Das aufgereufene Object wurde von den Clients getrennt." (The called object got disconnected from the clients.) This happens after excatly one of the 100+ problematic objects got deleted.

Comment: The Line "Next objDrawingObject" works fine a houndred times skipping all the objects that are not called "CustomShape 1" before the sub finds the first problem shape and deletes it.

Comment: Can you try iterating using a `For i = Tabelle1.DrawingObjects.Count to 0 Step -1 ` or something similar?

Comment: @Ryan Wildry: Not sure. I can't call the objects via "if DrawingObjects(i).name = ..." so maybe there is a way that I don't know of.

Comment: @andy01q It might not be possible to index them in that way (if `DrawingObjects` doesn't have a default property accepting an int like that). Maybe try `If DrawingObjects.Item(i) = ...`? Alternatively, could you try using the `Shapes` collection instead of `DrawingObjects` (which might be deprecated - it doesn't show up in my Object Explorer in Excel 2013)?

Comment: "For Each objShapes In Tabelle1.Shapes" Throws an error right away: Run time error -2147352567 (80020009): Automation Error Exceptional error occured. "DrawingObjects.Item(i)" throws an error which says object not found.

Comment: @andy01q That Automation Error is one of the worst errors to deal with because it's so incredibly vague. Often it has something to do with something being unloaded when it's expected to be loaded (e.g. accessing controls on an unloaded form, trying to save when there are no workbooks open...) Any chance one of those situations applies?

Comment: Not really. There are no forms and I didn't try to save. On my function way above that could've been plausible, because the Next statement seemed to fail to find the next object due to the previous having been deleted.

Comment: Try a preliminary loop (possibly without the GoTo statement) to first rename all `DrawingObjects` named "CustomShape 1" into "CustomShape 1", CustomShape 2", and so on. And then run the deletion loop for all `DrawingObjects` named "CustomShape *"

Comment: Use 2 loops, First add matching objects to an array.  Second delete the objects in the array.

Comment: @user3598756 I'm not sure whether this is going to help.

Comment: @Jules: This seems like a good solution. I hope I get time to try that soon.